# conversion http to https

Tags: php, ssl, web, web-services

[mysite](http://happylife.in/)

I want to move my site from HTTP TO HTTPS ,

Also i want to redirect my site when user type

1.IF THEY TYPE LIKE  **happy.in**      To  https://happylife.in

2.IF THEY TYPE LIKE  **http://happy.in**      To  https://happylife.in

3.IF THEY TYPE LIKE  **www.happy.in**      To  https://happylife.in

What things i have to ,

YET AM NOT STARTED ANY WORK FOR SSL,

Please guide me,

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to use https? Will there be an authentication process that provides access to non-public information? If not, then https is unnecessary.

Comment: STILL SITE NOT LAUNCHED..TEMP I PUT THAT FLASH..I EXCUSE FOR THAT...THANKS

Comment: Most important you need a SSL certificate.

Comment: 1) Get an SSL certificate and install it,
2) Setup a permanent redirect from http to https - you can most likely do it in the server setup.

Comment: We have purchased and installed ...

If i enter https.mysite.com then it show the site is secure....

Now what i want is ...When every user enter the url directly....

i want to redirect automatically to the https.mysite.com

Comment: HI ANY ONE GIVE SOME SUGGESTION FOR THIS QUESTION.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Install an SSL certificate

2) Put this in an .htaccess file in your root web directory:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.happylife.in/$1 [R,L]
```